# converted excel formal to DAX

Tags: dax

please anyone can help to convert this formal to Dax
=IF(COUNTIFS(D:D,D2,L:L,"Y")>1,"Only 1 Y contact","OK")

It is looking to see if there is more than one Y in a column (L:L) per patient id. (D:D)

Comment: You should include a bit more information regarding your model. Is it a single table? Try to include some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any DAX function that would count the number of occurrences of a sub string in a string, but one can use `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove each occurrences of a sub string in the string, then compute the length `LEN()` difference with original string :

```
IF(
  LEN('Table'[Column])-
    LEN( 
      SUBSTITUTE( 
        'Table'[Column],
        "Y",
        "" )
    ) > 1,
  "Only 1 Y contact",
  "OK")
```